# UISwipeGestureRecognizer for subviews (UIVIew) not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a View Controller with 3 subviews inside the self.view.
I'm trying to slide between them and it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizerLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) 
    {       
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && !([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]))
        {  
             [subview addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizerLeft];
             NSLog(@"Load 2");    
        }
    }
}

    -(void) didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) swipeRecognizer {
        NSLog(@"Load swipe");

        if (swipeRecognizer.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) 
        {
            NSLog(@"swipe Left"); 
            [self SlideToLeft];
        }
    }
```

I really see that "Load 2" is being printed 3 times but when I try to slide it's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UIScrollView here? That could be the problem.

I think you can just use the standard UIScrollView delegate methods in this situation:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Scrolled!");
}
```

Otherwise these guys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276391/uiswipegesturerecognizer-on-uiview-inside-uiscrollview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129334/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview-with-gesture-recognizers-enabled-for-sibl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview) had some trouble too, maybe the answers there could help you.

If you're not using a UIScrollView here? I should use one, why not? 3 Subviews and swiping to the next one sounds just like a nice UIScrollView example (use paging).

Good Luck!